# Chain slick sliders together

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

Im using slick slider to show screenshots of a desktop site and its mobile site.

Is there anyway to chain/delay the two sliders so that the mobile screen only changes after the desktop screen has changed?

I cant seem to get afterChange to work.

Heres my code:

```
<div class="case-screens">
   <div class="screen-desktop-wrapper">
      <div class="screen-desktop-slider">
         <div>1<img src="gfx/references/screen_desktop_scout_01.jpg">
         </div>
         <div>2<img src="gfx/references/screen_desktop_scout_01.jpg">
         </div>
         <div>3<img src="gfx/references/screen_desktop_scout_01.jpg">
         </div>
      </div>
      <img src="gfx/references/screen_desktop.png" class="desktop-frame">
   </div>
   <div class="screen-mobile-wrapper">
      <div class="screen-mobile-slider">
         <div>1<img src="gfx/references/screen_mobile_scout_01.jpg">
         </div>
         <div>2<img src="gfx/references/screen_mobile_scout_01.jpg">
         </div>
         <div>3<img src="gfx/references/screen_mobile_scout_01.jpg">
         </div>
      </div>
      <img src="gfx/references/screen_iphone.png" class="mobile-frame"> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Slick slider

```
$('.screen-desktop-slider').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    speed: 1500,
    accessibility: false,
    arrows:false,
    pauseOnHover:false,
    easing:'easeOutQuart',
    fade: true
});

$('.screen-mobile-slider').slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    speed: 1500,
    accessibility: false,
    arrows:false,
    pauseOnHover:false,
    easing:'easeOutQuart',
    fade: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set `autoplay: false` to the mobile slider and remove the `autoplaySpeed` setting. Then you'll want to invoke the `afterChange` event like so:

```
$('.screen-desktop-slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    $('.screen-mobile-slider').slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide, false);
});
```

The `currentSlide` argument represents the current slide's index. So if you want to the change the mobile's slider slide, call the `slickGoTo` method giving the slide index to go to. `slickGoTo`'s second argument that I set to `false` indicates whether or not to animate. You can omit it if you want animation (default value is `true`).